# Could not continue the converting process from HTML element to DOM due to messy input data

Tags: php, xml, dom

I need your help...

I have a function to manipulate the HTML element to change the image url using DOM parse. My function was working properly. Here's my code:

```
//Update image src with new src
function upd_img_src_in_html($html_src='', $new_src='')
{
    if($html_src == '' || $new_src == ''):
        return '';
    endif;

    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->loadHTML($html_src, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    $imgNodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('img');
    for ($i = $imgNodes->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $imgNode = $imgNodes->item($i);
        $image_file_names = pathinfo($imgNode->getAttribute('src'), PATHINFO_BASENAME);

        if(!empty($image_file_names)):
            $imgNode->setAttribute('src', $new_src.$image_file_names);
            $imgNode->setAttribute('style', 'max-width:90%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;');
        endif;
    }
    return html_entity_decode($xml->saveHTML());
}
```

However a lot of problems come after I made this function.

No 1: `result_box` already defined in Entity line 1

[image]

No. 2: unexpected line tag..

[image]

I cannot control at all the input from `$html_src=''` to make it run smoothly. I've tried some effort on dealing with the problem 1 but still not success. For example I used `libxml_use_internal_errors()` but still got the error.

The second problem I can not overcome it. Is it any easiest way to handle only to change image src instead of using `DOMDocument()`?

The answers from expert really needed here. Please give me some advice on how to deal with these problems.

Thank you..

Comment: the html may be invalid preventing the dom parsing from working.  can you use regular expressions instead of dom parsing?

Comment: I was tried it before..is it practical in large DOM content? Sometimes the reqular expression can not read at all since a lot of tags

Comment: most of the time i would say no, but if you control this html file where the images are, or you don't expect it to change, then what you are trying to do here is [feasible in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491)

Comment: Try using `libxml_use_internal_errors()`. The messages look more like parser warnings, not actual fatal errors. And this are exceptions, you can catch them.

Comment: Can you post the sample values of `$html_src` and `$new_src`?

Comment: @ThW I liked to here that...I will update my answer soon...

Comment: @web-nomad I'll update my answer

Comment: @Imran Looking at the errors you have listed, it seems that the html contains more than 1 element with the same `ID`. You can try to use [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with messy HTML and DOMDocument is to use the [PHP tidy extension](http://php.net/tidy) first, which will correct all the errors that are in it.